# Angular2 move animation

Tags: animation, angular

Angular 1 handles enter, leave and move animations. The Angular 2 documentation describes how to do enter and leave animations (void => * and * => void), but how can one implement move animations in Angular 2?

Answer (score 2):

Read [Angular's official guide for animations](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) if you haven't already.

You define animation states and the transitions between them. For instance:

```
animations: [
  trigger('heroState', [
    state('inactive', style({
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('active',   style({
      backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
      transform: 'scale(1.1)'
    })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

`inactive` and `active` can be replaced with any arbitrary strings and you can have as many unique states as you wish, but there must be a valid transition to each one or else the animation won't happen. `void` is a special case for when elements aren't yet attached to the view and `*` is a wildcard, applying to *any* of the defined states.

EDIT:

Hmm... well, for one thing, you might be able to use [this Sortable library](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable). It claims to support Angular 2 and is pure Javascript (no jQuery) so theoretically, it should work well but I have not used it myself.

Otherwise, I am certain it would be possible purely inside Angular 2, but it would probably require some fairly clever code. Relative motion (irrespective of a component or element's particular position) is easy with `transform: translateY()` property. The problem is that Angular 2 animation states only apply if the component is in that state so if you give it a translateY(-20px) to move an element up a position, it's not going to keep that position if you want to want to move it up again.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/J1KqXaUwGeUF3sw2seAW?p=preview) for the solution I have come up with.

```
template: `
  <div #thisElement>
    <div class="div-box" @moveState="state">Click buttons to move <div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="moveUp()">Up</button>
  <button (click)="moveDown()">Down</button>
`,
```

I defined animation states for 'moveUp' and 'moveDown' that ONLY apply *during* the actual animation and a 'static' state that is applied when the component isn't moving.

```
animations: [
trigger('moveState', [
  state('moveUp', style({
    transform: 'translateY(-30px)';
  })),
  state('moveDown',   style({
    transform: 'translateY(30px)';
  })),
  state('static', style({
    transform: 'translateY(0)';
  })),
  transition('* => moveUp', animate('100ms ease-in')),
  transition('* => moveDown', animate('100ms ease-out')),
  transition('* => static', animate('0ms linear'))
])
]
```

For the function that actually initiates the animation, it applies the 'moveUp' or 'moveDown' state and then starts a timeout that triggers a callback after an amount of time equal to the length of the transition. In the callback, it sets the animation state to 'static' (the transition to the 'static' state is set to 0 ms so we don't actually animate it moving back to a static position). Then we use Renderer to apply a translation for where we want it to ultimately end up (calculated using a position property that would define it's position relative to where it was initially, not it's position in the array). The Renderer applies its styles separately from the animation so we can apply both without them conflicting with each other.

```
export class MyComponent {
  state = 'static';
  @ViewChild('thisElement') thisBox: ElementRef;
  position: number = 0;

//...

  moveUp() {
    this.state = 'moveUp';  
    this.position--;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.state = 'static';
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.thisBox.nativeElement, 'transform', 'translateY(' + String(this.position * 30) + 'px)');
    }, 100)
  }
  moveDown() {
    this.state = 'moveDown';
    this.position++;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.state = 'static';
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.thisBox.nativeElement, 'transform', 'translateY(' + String(this.position * 30) + 'px)');
    }, 100)
  }
//...
}
```

This is only an example of how you can animate moves without having to define states for each possible position it could be in. As far as triggering the animations on array manipulation, you'll have to figure that out for yourself. I would use some kind of implementation with EventEmitters or Subjects to send events to the components that would then decide on whether or not they need to animate or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my usecase is an array of components displayed with *ngFor. A user action in my application will trigger two elements in the array to be swapped. I want this swapping to be animated in the view. This can not be handled by state changes within the component itself, because the state within the component itself is not changed. I need the animation to be triggered by the array manipulation itself. This was handled perfectly well by the ngMove (in combination with ngRepeat) in Angular1. How should this be done in Angular2?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your thorough answer and will look into it.

Comment: your plunk not working, I hope to see your useful solution

Comment: Just doesn't work as an answer and by all accounts the plunker never worked. Not particularly helpful as answers go.